# Ipython completion in elpy

Tags: python, ipython, elpy

My `elpy` uses `ipython` as the interactive interpreter.  It does not, however, emulate `ipython`'s history-informed autocomplete feature (for lack of a better term).

That is: within an `ipython` session launched from the terminal, if you want to execute a line previously executed, you can type the first part of the line, and up-arrow will only display consistent previous commands.

In the `ipython` shell launched from `elpy` (with `C-c C-c`), I can execute previous commands with `C-p`, but I cannot view only those commands consistent with a given partial command. How can I utilize this very useful feature of `ipython` within the emacs `elpy` shell?

Comment: Try `M-x comint-previous-matching-input`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't use eply, I use emacs 25.1.1 with company-jedi with the following:

```
(setq
 python-shell-interpreter "ipython3"
 python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt --pprint")
```

Inside emacs *Python*

Python 3.6.0, Anaconda 4.3.0, Ipython 5.1.0

```
In[1]: x = 10
In[2]: x = 125
In[3]: x =      # type M-p
```

I get history items 1 and 2 and Input restored.
That example seems to be working for me.

Please share what your emacs version, (I)python version and a code snippet. 
It may be useful to file a bug report with elpy if that is the problem.

Comment: Yes, this works. Even with elpy. If you start a command and press `M-p` it completes it. However, in the normal IPython shell, commands from previous sessions can be accessed in the same way. In my emacs setup, this doesn't seem possible.